# Do I need to uninstall Python package before upgrading to newer version?

Tags: python, windows, distutils

I'm running Python on Windows and usually install packages using pre-built binaries.  When I upgrade packages (ex. from matplotlib-1.0.0 to matplotlib-1.1.1) do I need to uninstall the earlier version first?

I did a test upgrading matplotlib without uninstalling the previous version and everything seems to be okay.  `matplotlib.__version__` shows '1.1.1'.  So did distutils just overwrite files, potentially leaving old files cluttering my site-packages folder?  Or did the installer look for previous installations, remove those first, and then install the new version?

Comment: When I look in the Windows Control Panel at my installed programs, the previous version of matplotlib is gone after installing the newer version, so it seems that the installer either removed the old package or told Windows that the old package has been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `pip`, you can do `pip install package --upgrade`, but you'll see that essentially it's the same as uninstall followed by a fresh install.

Comment: I'm not using `pip`.  I download a pre-built executable for Windows (ex. matplotlib-1.1.1.win32-py2.7.exe) which runs an install wizard.

Comment: I tested both cases (fresh install vs install over previous), then compared the two matplotlib folders using WinMerge and found additional files left over from the previous version.  So there doesn't appear to be any magic going on with the Windows distutils over what pip upgrade does (uninstall + fresh install).

Comment: OP uses pre-built binaries which pip doesn't handle so he can't use pip to install them. He can use `easy_install` though.

Answer (score 0):

you have to uninstall it:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

This will clutter your site package or worse

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need a clean install. I've shot my leg when upgrading from matplotlib 1.2.1 to 1.3.1 w/o removing first the old package.